# Python: open a URL with accent

Tags: python, utf-8, urllib2

In Python 2.7, I want to open a URL which contains accents (**the link itself**, not the page to which it's pointing). If I use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2


test = "https://www.notifymydevice.com/push?ApiKey=K6HGFJJCCQE04G29OHSRBIXI&PushTitle=Les%20accents%20:%20éèçà&PushText=Messages%20éèçà&"

urllib2.urlopen(test)
```

My accents are converted to gibberish (Ã, ¨, ©, etc rather than the éèà I expect).

I've searched for that kind of issue and so I tried with *urllib2.urlopen(test.encode('utf-8'))* but Python throws an error in that case:

> File "test.py", line 10, in
>   
>       urllib2.urlopen(test.encode('utf8')) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ApiKey! 

Comment: It's a testing key @tif, I created it for stackoverflow only ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the string with a `u`. I get no errors trying it out in repl using this

```
import urllib
test = u'https://www.notifymydevice.com/push?ApiKey=K6HGFJJCCQE04G29OHSRBIXI&PushTitle=Les%20accents%20:%20éèçà&PushText=Messages%20éèçà&'
urllib.urlopen(test.encode("UTF-8"))
```

The `u` prefix is for [unicode strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)

Comment: Excellent! I spent one hour on it with no result and you solved it in a matter of seconds :-)

Comment: Why is it working with _urllib_ and not _urllib2_, though? @chevybow

Comment: @Nicolas are you getting any errors with urllib2? I am not getting any errors using either- you should be able to continue using urllib2. I used urlllib in my code snippet because I skimmed through your code and didn't realize you were using urllib2

Comment: I don't get an error in Python but my message isn't encoded properly.

I use notifymydevice.com to send notifications on my Android smartphone and with the 'u' and urllib2, I have "Ã©Ã¨Ã§Ã" where I should get "éèçà"

See: https://image.ibb.co/hCe6bK/urllib.png

Answer (score 1):

If you call `encode` on a `str`, Python has to first decode it to `unicode` so it can encode that Unicode to UTF-8. And to decode it, it has to guess what encoding you used, because you didn't tell it. So it guesses `'ascii'` (actually, it guesses whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` says, but that's usually `'ascii'`), which fails.

At any rate, there are two possible problems here, which have different solutions. So, you need to figure out which one you have, before trying to fix it.

---

Try printing out the individual bytes of the string—or, more simply, the `repr`:

```
print repr(test)
```

- If the `é` shows up as `\xc3\xa9`, it's UTF-8.
- If it shows up as `\xe9`, it's Latin-1 (or cp1252 or something else Latin-1-compatible).
- If it shows up as something else, it's a different character set, and you'll have to work out which one.

---

If you're giving Python Latin-1 source and telling it it's UTF-8, it won't complain, but it means you'll be sending Latin-1 bytes where you think you're sending UTF-8 characters, and you'll get mojibake all over the place.

The fix is to save the source code as UTF-8 in your text editor.

---

If it already *is* UTF-8, then the problem is that the server isn't expecting the URL to be UTF-8.

The URL standards don't mandate any particular meaning for (`%`-encoded) non-ASCII bytes; any server can do anything it wants with them. And if you're talking to a server that treats such bytes as, say, cp1252, but you're sending it UTF-8, you're going to get mojibake.

The fix for this is to reconfigure the server to handle UTF-8 if you control the server, or to send strings in the character set the server wants if you don't.

Comment: The 'é' was showing up as \xc3\xa9. Are you sure it's UTF-8?

When I add the 'u' in front of the string, it then shows up as \xe9

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, I'm sure. The character `é` has Unicode code point U+00E9, so when you `print repr(u'é')`, you see `u'\xe9'). Its UTF-8 encoding is the two bytes `C3`, `A9`, so when you `print repr('é')` (assuming you've got UTF-8-encoded source) you see `'\xc3\xa9'`.

Comment: Things work now, so I don't really need to go further but I'd like to understand.

What does the u'\xe9' stand for if it's a UTF-8 string?

Comment: @Nicolas That question doesn't make sense. A `u'…'` string is a Unicode string, not a UTF-8 string. `u'\xe9'` is the Unicode string whose only character is Unicode character number `0xe9`, aka `U+00E9`, aka `é`. A UTF-8 string is _not_ a Unicode string, it's a byte string, just like a Latin-1 string or any other kind of byte string. The Unicode string `u'\xe9'` encodes to UTF-8 as the byte string `'\xc3\xa9'`.

Comment: I got mixed up between unicode and UTF-8, sorry @abarnert

Comment: @Nicolas Yeah, it's easy to get mixed up. (It's even easier to mix things up with UTF-32…)