# Using urllib to open a url with an accent

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to open a url using urlopen in urllib, but am getting an error due to an accent mark in the URL:

```
import urllib
import ssl
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raúl_Grijalva'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=context)
```

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfa' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715290/python-open-a-url-with-accent) answer suggesting adding a u to the string and encoding, but this gives me a different error:

```
import urllib
import ssl
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
url = u'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raúl_Grijalva'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url.encode('UTF-8'), context=context)
```

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I did notice in that answer they use `urllib.urlopen` instead of `urllib.request.urlopen` and I'm not exactly sure what the difference between these is, but the former throws an error that urllib doesn't have that attribute.

How can I properly handle this character in the url?

Comment: I'm running this in a Jupyter Notebook with a Python 3 kernel and the code otherwise works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `parse.quote()` to escape the text with accent character seems to work:

```
from urllib import request, parse
import ssl

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
path = parse.quote('wiki/Raúl_Grijalva')

page = request.urlopen(url + path, context=context)
```